# Is there a way to access a SQL database from another IP address in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am making a game and want to make a SQL database with usernames and passwords to test accessing a SQL database from other IP addresses. I want to know what I do to accomplish that. I want the user to write in their username and password, and the database checks if it is correct, and returns if it is accurate. And it all checks in a database within my computer, my IP address.

Comment: A database should be accessed server side *by a server side app* really as securing it is essentially not possible otherwise

Comment: You need to add a user like "USER@YOUR_IP" to mysql... Your game needs 3 layers. The database. Your backend server, which communicates with the database. And the game, which communicates with the backend server.  If you don't need a backend server, you could probably get away with saving the user's state to a file or SQLight or something...